# INET time synchronization of IEEE 802.11 stations

Tags: omnet++, inet

Is there an option for time-synchronization e.g. IEEE AVB/TSN of wireless nodes (IEEE 802.11 stations) within the inet framework?

And if so, how is the resource reservation realized on the medium access level?
The point coordination function (PCF) is still not implemented so far: https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/master/src/inet/linklayer/ieee80211/mac/coordinationfunction/Pcf.h#L40

Answer (score 1):

**2020-04-21 UPDATE:**

Avnu has a white paper on the concept: https://avnu.org/wireless-tsn-paper/

> Avnu Alliance members... wrote the *Avnu Alliance Wireless TSN – Definitions, Use Cases & Standards Roadmap* white paper in an effort to generate awareness and start defining work required in Avnu to enable wireless TSN extensions in alignment with wired TSN systems and operation models.

**2018-04-03 UPDATE:**

[IEEE Std. 802.1AS-2011](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5741898/) (gPTP) has a clause 12 titled "Media-dependent layer specification for IEEE 802.11 links." So, **yes**, it seems time synchronization is possible over WIFI, and is in fact defined in an IEEE standard.

**2017-12-13 UPDATE:**

It looks like the OpenAvnu project has been working on this idea. Check out this pull request, which seems to implement the precision time-stamping required for AVB on a WIFI connection.

- [OpenAvnu Pull Request #734: "Added wireless timestamper and port code"](https://github.com/AVnu/OpenAvnu/pull/734)

---

This should probably be asked in multiple questions, with each question relating to the implementation of one of the core AVB/TSN protocols on a WIFI (802.11) network. Audio video bridging (AVB) and time sensitive networking (TSN) are not IEEE standards or protocols. What we call AVB or TSN (I'm just going to use AVB from now on) is a singular name for the use and implementation of multiple IEEE standards in order to achieve real-time media transfer.

These core protocols are:

- [IEEE Std. 802.1BA-2011](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/802.1BA-2011.html): Profiles and configurations of IEEE standards which define what an AVB endpoint or bridge needs to do. This is the closest we get to one single standard for AVB.
- [IEEE Std. 1722(-2016)](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1722-2016.html): A Layer 2 audio video transport protocol (AVTP)
- [IEEE Std. 1722.1(-2013)](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1722.1-2013.html): Audio video discover, enumeration, connection management and control (AVDECC) for 1722-based devices
- [IEEE Std. 802.1AS(-2011)](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/802.1AS-2011.html): Generalized precision time protocol (gPTP)
- [IEEE Std. 802.1Q(-2014)](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/802.1Q-2014.html): FQTSS and SRP

(note that according to the [IEEE TSN webpage](http://www.ieee802.org/1/pages/tsn.html), currently published TSN-specific standards will be rolled into 802.1Q, so the list above should still be accurate)

Because stream reservation (SRP), timing (gPTP), and media transport (1722 or 1723) are independent, your question should probably be asking about them independently.

> 1. How can/should IEEE 802.1AS (gPTP) be implemented in a WIFI (802.11) network?
> 2. How can/should IEEE 802.1Q (SRP and FQTSS) be implemented in a WIFI network?

---

**1.** I have nowhere near the experience these standards developers have, and some of them have explored gPTP on WIFI extensively. The "how" of gPTP is well explained by Kevin Stanton of Intel [here](http://www.ieee802.org/1/files/public/docs2008/as-kbstanton-8021AS-overview-for-dot11aa-1108.pdf).

And for WIFI in particular, Norman Finn from Cisco had some notes on using gPTP with WIFI networks [here](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/6tsch/current/pdf0BD87rc3vC.pdf).

I couldn't find anything that explicitly laid out how best to use/implement gPTP with WIFI. Ethernet is really where a lot of this is happening right now.

---

**2.** Craig Gunther from Harman says:

> Simply implement[ing] the SRP control protocol without performing the related reservation actions. ... 802.11ak along with 802.1Qbz may make this much simpler. .... 802.11ac and 802.11ad have created some interesting new technologies that may help with reservations...

Source: http://www.ieee802.org/1/files/public/docs2014/at-cgunther-srp-for-802-11-0114-v01.pdf

---

Personally, I feel like guaranteed latency and reliability are very hard to ask for with a network that has to do things like carrier-sense multiple access with collision avoidance (CSMA/CA), but that's just my inexperienced opinion. It certainly would be cool, but it seems very... challenging.